# Acronym regex works in .NET online tool, but not in C# code

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using a .NET regex checker, http://regexstorm.net/tester

to test a string to match acronyms

```
(?<=\s|^)((?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,})(?=[[:punct:]]?(?:\s|$))

Away from keyboard is shortened into A.F.K.
```

The online tool correctly match A.F.K.

But the C# does not!

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\s|^)((?:[a-zA-Z]\.){2,})(?=[[:punct:]]?(?:\s|$))");
var match = regex.Match("Away from keyboard is shortened into A.F.K.");
if(!match.Success)
    throw new NoMatchException("no match found"); // throws
```

Comment: 1) `[[:punct:]]` does not work as you expect, .NET regex does not support POSIX character classes (to match punctuation and symbols, you need `[\p{P}\p{S}]`, or  `(?:_|[^\w\s])`), 2) [your code works in C#](https://ideone.com/jC2m2k)

Comment: that compiler online you tried is .NET 4.7.X, I have net core3.1 and there it don't work, I'll try wwith the other expression

Comment: ok `[\p{P}\p{S}]` worked I will accept it as answer if you answer it. Thank you